# Use gorm condition to judge timestamp

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

Ask for advice:

```
db.Unscoped().Where("deleted_on != ? ", 0).Delete(&Tag{})
```

deleted_on is of type int

If deleted_on is a timestamp and the value is null, how should it be expressed?

Answer (score 0):

You should  use postgres query. Like this

```
db.Unscoped().Where("deleted_on isnull ").Delete(&Tag{})
```

Comment: in Go language default value of integer is 0, but in postgres integer can be null.